# What format is the block timestamp?

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js, extrinsic

I'm using **@polkadot-js** to decode extrinsic data. The following method call returns a timestamp at a specific block, but I don't know how to parse this.

I tried assuming that it's a unix timestamp in **seconds** and parsing it like so, but it doesn't fit. Is this in **nanoseconds**? **milliseconds**?

How can I parse it into a date object in my favorite programming language?

```
const timestamp = await api.query.timestamp.now.at(blockHash);
```

The docs: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#now-u64

Example: `1590512778000`
(*Could it be that my timestamps being incorrectly decoded?*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substrate are time stamped by a number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

This convention is widely adopted by many modern programming environments. Here is a simple example in JS with the timestamp you provided:

```
let time = new Date(1590512778000)
time.toString()
> "Tue May 26 2020 11:06:18 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)"
```

Comment: Originally unix timestamps are represented by seconds. It's worth clarifying that in Substrate this number is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. I guess it's an epoch mill

use below site.

https://www.epochconverter.com/